# Why are some tags outlined differently than others?

Tags: support, tags

I wonder why some tags placed under questions look slightly like 3d-buttons, but others look like 2d with a thicker, darker border? I only notice a difference here on Meta SO.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Thick grey border - Required tag

Each question must include at least one of these tags:

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
- [support](/questions/tagged/support)

#### Red tags - Moderator only

Only moderators can set these to a question:

- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)
- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)
- [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced)

Questions migrated from the other sites to Meta, along with those older than the tag requirements, may slip through without a required tag.

Comment: Thank you! I could have seen it for myself ;)