# Why do some tags have a dark brown background?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some tags outlined differently than others?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25063/why-are-some-tags-outlined-differently-than-others)

I found that some tag with dark red/brown background like [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and some other tags with a border like [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [support](/questions/tagged/support), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

How are these tags different from tags without a border?

Comment: See the legend at the bottom of the [tags page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags)

Comment: See [this `[faq]` answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/131713).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ones with dark grey borders (discussion, feature request, bug) are meta tags used to describe a problem.

- Discussion is used for talking about the site (like this)
- Feature request is if you want something changing
- Bug is if something is not displaying correctly, or you've found a problem with the site.

The dark red tags are *moderator* tags. They can be only added by moderators to mark a question as declined, complete, deferred, or by-design.

- Declined or deferred are typically issues to "feature-request" tags. They mean the feature has been decline (i.e. Won't happen), or deferred (i.e. planned, but not yet)
- Complete could be added after a bug-tagged question is resolved.
- by-design could be a question tagged when a user mistakes a bug as a feature, for example, the highly-common 101-rep for new users. That's not a *bug*, that *by-design*.

As Anna mentioned below, there are indeed others.

The "normal" tags are the ones you use to describe the question.

Comment: and the [closed] one in the title means (in this case) your question was identical to a previously-asked one.

Answer (score 3):

[support](/questions/tagged/support), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) are special Meta tags that suggest what type of meta post the question is trying to be. For example, yours is actually [support](/questions/tagged/support), since you're asking about how an existing feature of the site works rather than discussing a policy or proposing a new feature. At least one of these tags must be present on every question.

Red tags, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred), [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced), [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) and [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), are moderator-only tags that are used to describe how a request is being handled.

The rest are just normal tags.

You can read more about each tag by clicking on it and reading its tag wiki. Some of the regular tags are missing wikis, but most of them should be pretty self-explanatory.